# Why isn't there a getContentView() method for Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

The `Activity` class has a `setContentView()` method.  The `PopupWindow` Class has a `getContentView()` method but nothing else does.  Is there another way to get the main content view for an activity?

Answer (score 53):

I was able to get to the contents of an Activity with this call:

```
ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView();
```

You should probably check that getDecorView returns an instanceof ViewGroup for all cases, but with a LinearLayout in the Activity the code above runs fine. To get to the LinearLayout you could then just:

```
LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout)view.getChildAt(0);
```

And if you have a function like this:

```
void logContentView(View parent, String indent) {
    Log.i("test", indent + parent.getClass().getName());
    if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)parent;
        for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++)
            logContentView(group.getChildAt(i), indent + " ");
    }
}
```

You could iterate through all views and log their class names with the following call inside your Activity:

```
logContentView(getWindow().getDecorView(), "");
```

Comment: +1 Used ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView(); to clear all views from an activity by calling view.removeAllViews(); - thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 52):

Following line will do the trick:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

it is essentially same as (it needs to be called on the context of an Activity)

```
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking for this as well,  but I just thought that it might be easier to add an id to the outermost ViewGroup.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/outer">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

I'll keep looking for a few more minutes, though. I'm into it so that I can use [findViewWithTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag%28java.lang.Object%29) from the outermost layout.

Comment: This also works with findViewById. I hadn't realised that you could put an id in the outermost tag of the xml. This is how I use: thisView = (View) findViewById(R.id.parent_view);