# How to react to spinner item selection in an AlertDialog.Builder-generated dialog?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-alertdialog

In my application, I display a dialog box with the following code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        getActivity());
final View myDialogForm = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
        .inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);

builder.setTitle(R.string.addCompanyDialogTitle)
    .setView(myDialogForm)
    .create()
    .show();
```

It contains a `Spinner` and a `TextView`. When the user selects something in the spinner, the text view must be updated.

How can I implement this (react to spinner selection in a dialog box generated by `AlertDialog.Builder`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in this way:

1) Modify the code above like this:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        getActivity());
final View myDialogForm = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
        .inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);

final Spinner mySpinner = 
    (Spinner) addCompanyDialogForm.findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);

finalOutputSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

builder.setTitle(R.string.addCompanyDialogTitle)
    .setView(myDialogForm)
    .create()
    .show();
```

2) Make the class implement the interface [`AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html).

3) Implement methods of that interface in that class:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> aParent, final View aView,
        final int aPosition, final long aRowId) {
    // aRowId contains the index of the selected item
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(final AdapterView<?> aParent) {
    // Nothing is selected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate trough the views of your dialog using a recursive function such as:

```
    Dialog di = builder.setTitle(R.string.addCompanyDialogTitle).setView(myDialogForm).create();
    updateMessage(di.getWindow().getDecorView());
    di.show();
    //...
    private void updateMessage(View parent){
     if(parent instanceof ViewGroup){
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) parent;
        for(int i=0; i < vg.getChildCount();i++){
            View v = vg.getChildAt(i); 
            if(v instanceof RelativeLayout){
                RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) v;
                TextView tv = (TextView) rl.getChildAt(1);
                Spinner sp = (Spinner) rl.getChildAt(0);
                sp.setOnItemSelectedListener( 
                                        //..
                                        tv.setText(sp_value); 
                                        //..
                                    )
                break;
            } else {
                updateMessage(v);
            }
        }                       
    }
   }
```

You can control when you are on your R.layout.my_dialog with the help of `instanceOf` your_root_view, in my example it is a RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Spinner ... />

    <TextView ... />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736367/why-isnt-there-a-getcontentview-method-for-activity/4240254#4240254)