# Android PDF generation

Tags: java, android, pdf-generation

I tried to learn how to generate PDF for my Android application.
I followed the official documentation but the code didn't work.
the compiler found me some compilation error but all I did was to copy/paste the code from the code.
please take a look at the code and tell me why (:

```
 PrintAttributes printAttributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder().
         setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
         .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
         .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
         .build();


PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(this, printAttributes);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}



// crate a page description
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), 1).create();

// start a page
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

// draw something on the page
View content = getContentView();
content.draw(page.getCanvas());

// finish the page
document.finishPage(page);
// add more pages
// write the document content
document.writeTo(getOutputStream());

// close the document
document.close();
```

Comment: You need wrap the PDF generation code into a method.

Comment: @AllanPereira if i wrap generation code into a method, I still have these errors : 
https://gyazo.com/d83aff5a0a4afddfc7a10ae85973a633

(sorry i had to screen it, because the errors were not inline..)

Answer (score 0):

1. `PageInfo.Builder` does not take the parameters you used. Try to replace

   ```
    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = 
            new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), 1).create();
   ```

   with

   ```
   PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(100,100,1).create();`
   ```

   Please check the documentation for
   [PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder.html)
2. `getContentView()` is not called from the right class, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736367/why-isnt-there-a-getcontentview-method-for-activity)
3. `getOutputStream()` does not exist for the Activity class. If what you want to do is to copy the content into a file, you should probably create a new file, and the copy the output to that file.
4. all your code needs to be enclosed in a method and then called from the `onCreate()` method.

For more information about generating PDF for Android, please check [this link].[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-an-android-app)